# Incorrect product of two INT_MAX numbes in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, overflow, printf, multiplication

In my case, product of two INT_MAX numbers is `296447233`, which is incorrect.

```
long long int product = 0;
product = 2137483647 * 2137483647;
printf("product: %lli\n", product);
```

What I am doing wrong, and how to correct it ??
Thanks !

Comment: Um...INT_MAX is 2147483647 (for 32-bit ints). You're shy by 10000000.

Comment: Oh, no !!!!!! Ye, I got INT_MAX wrong. Thanks for pointing it out !

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Both of your `2137483647` are of type `int`. So they stay that type and overflow.

Make them `long long`s:

```
product = 2137483647LL * 2137483647LL;
```

or cast:

```
product = (long long)2137483647 * 2137483647;
```

Comment: So, basically, product of two ints just overflows, even though I am assigning it to long long int ? Thanks for the Answer !

Comment: Correct. In your example, the conversion happens *after* the multiply. So it overflows before it gets promoted to `long long`.

Comment: The compiler will treat the two numbers as ints, does the maths and then thinks about putting the value into `product`.

Answer (score 6):

Try

```
product = 2137483647LL * 2137483647LL;
```

to ensure that the compile treats the numbers as long long