# Why does implicit type conversion results incorrectly in this code?

Tags: c++, types

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int number=65536;
    long long temp=number*number;
    std::cout << temp << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Square of `65536` is obviously out of `int`'s range. Now, if I had declared `temp` as an `int`, I would understand why this fails. But even though it's `long long` , the output is always `0`. I believe this is somewhat related to implicit type conversion but I can't understand why the result is `0`.

Is this because c++ simply doesn't allow converting `int` to `long`? If so, then why does this work with smaller numbers?

Comment: There must be a better dupe, if at all: 65536 is rarely INT_MAX. (I don't know of any system where INT_MAX is an even number).

Comment: @Bathsheba How does it matter whether we use `INT_MAX` or some other pair of numbers whose product overflow `int`, but not `long long`?

Comment: It doesn't but the duplicate wasn't exact enough (for gold hammer). Continuing on this vein you end up with the inevitable consequence of every C++ question asked being a dupe of the standard.

Comment: @Bathsheba I disagree as literal substitution of just the variable names and numbers would make each answer to one question an answer to the other ([example](http://pastebin.com/Ch5x2P1D) with [Mystical's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9504511/3002139)), which is very far away from "dupe of the standard". But I only get one vote, so vOv

Comment: I personally refrain from gold hammer closing a question as a duplicate unless the case is *really* clear. The duplicate closed reason does state "exact duplicate".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

(Note that the range of an `int` can be as small as -32767 to +32767.)

`number * number` is evaluated in `int` arithmetic since both arguments are of type `int`. The behaviour of your program is *undefined* due to your `int` overflowing.

The fact that you want to assign the result to a `long long` is not relevant.

One solution would be to write `1LL * number * number` to force promotion of the arguments to `long long` types.

Comment: I now understand why this happens. It brought up a new question to my mind though, why does it have to be like this? Wouldn't it be convenient if compiler could deduce that the result is going to be assigned to a `long long`?

Comment: @zeke no it would not. You suggest that `lonl long l = n * n;` is different than `func( n * n );` or something like that. No, thanks.

Comment: @zeke: VBA attempts to do that with disastrous results.

Comment: @zeke: It doesn't *have* to be like this - but the approach taken by C (and C++) is that in general, the value of an expression is entirely dependant on that expression and nothing else.

Comment: @Slava If `func` took a `long long` argument, I would expect behaviour to be the same.  Of course, this would have an "interesting" impact on overload resolution...

Comment: @MartinBonner or `func()` can be a template. Anyway I do not want expression change it's value and behavior depends on where it is put on. C++ is already overcomplicated enough.

Answer (score 3):

The type used for an operation depends on the *operands* used by that operation.

In the operation `number*number`, both operands are `int`. They are not small integer types and they are both of the same type, so there will be no implicit promotion. The multiplication will get carried out on type `int` and the result will be of type `int`.

That you happen to assign the result to a `long` afterwards doesn't affect the calculation at all.

The solution is to cast one or both operands to a type large enough to hold the result of the calculation.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler treats the multiplication as a multiplication between two `int` variables. It is the *result* of that multiplication that is converted to a `long long` for the initialization of the `temp` variable.

At least one of the operands of the multiplication needs to be a `long long` for overflow to not happen.